TKinter Dropdown options values
I have a Tkinter dropdown with these options:
OPTIONS = [ 
    "ME", 
    "MA", 

] 

How can I use the equivalent of an HTML SELECT which offers a display and a value for each option item such that the value (state abbreviation) is returned when the state full name is selected?:
OPTIONS = [ 
    "Maine", ME
    "Massachusetts", CA

] 


html or webbrowser?

You can use a dictionary with the long names as keys and use those keys as the values of the dropdown.  Then you can get the state abbreviation by the selected long name using the dictionary.
